# How do I update a Pymongo document with another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I am aware of the `update` and `update_one` methods, however I haven't seen anything related to updating documents with other dictionaries.

For example, if I have the document:

```
{
  "bang": "Foo",
  "bar": "baz"
}
```

How can I update it with a dictionary `{'bang': 'bong'}` that changes `Foo` to `bong`?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand your question. Are you trying to replace `Foo` to `bong` and `baz` to `bar`. If yes, can you also show what pymongo database declaration have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want to update a field with a dictionary's value.

Then, try the sample code:

**Mongo Collection:**

```js
{
  "bang": "Foo",
  "bar": "baz"
}
```

**Python Program:**

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongo = MongoClient()
db = mongo.test #replace test with your db name
coll = db.testColl #replace testColl with your collection name
d = {'bang': 'bong'}
coll.update_one({}, {'$set': {'bang': d['bang']}})
```

**Output:**

```js
{
    "bang" : "bong",
    "bar" : "baz"
}
```

If I this isn't what you need, then let me know.